# Visual Studio Mac Error ! Custom Command Execution Failed

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I recently updated my Visual Studio for Mac and getting an error after build as "Custom Command execution failed". Any help appreciated !

Comment: Please update your questions with ide error log

Comment: Build succeeded.


    6 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:27.90

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Custom command failed (exit code: 1)
Custom command failed (exit code: 1)
Build: 2 errors, 9 warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error was due XCode command line tools selection. This command fixed the problem.

> ~$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer